# Install nginx-lua-modules error

Tags: nginx, lua

error:

```
/usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-0.10.10/src/ngx_http_lua_module.c: In 
function ‘ngx_http_lua_merge_srv_conf’:
/usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-0.10.10/src/ngx_http_lua_module.c:1022:37: error: passing argument 2 of ‘SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
                                 ngx_http_lua_ssl_sess_fetch_handler);
                                 ^
In file included from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.h:15:0,
             from src/core/ngx_core.h:83,
             from /usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-0.10.10/src/ddebug.h:13,
             from /usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-0.10.10/src/ngx_http_lua_module.c:11:
/usr/local/src/openssl-1.1.0g/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:639:6: note: expected ‘struct SSL_SESSION * (*)(struct ssl_st *, const unsigned char *, int,  int *)’ but argument is of type ‘struct SSL_SESSION * (*)(struct SSL *, u_char *, int,  int *)’
 void SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb(SSL_CTX *ctx,
  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/src/ngx_http_lua_module.o] error 1

make[1]:leaving `/usr/local/src/nginx-1.10.3'
make: *** [build] error 2
```

situation:

```
nginx -V:
--prefix=/etc/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre=/usr/local/src/pcre-8.39 --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params --http-scgi-temp-path=/etc/nginx/scgi_params --with-http_v2_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-ipv6 --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.1.0g
```

in this situation . make && make install is success

```
--add-module=/usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-0.10.10   --add-module=/usr/local/src/ngx_devel_kit-0.3.0
```

but after adding lua module ,error appear .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change version OpenSSL 1.1.0 to OpenSSL 1.0.2